# RetroFit Complex Query Parameters

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need to generate the following query string from RetroFit. I know that I can repeat query elements easily enough. Just need it formatted so that each element takes the form of assessment[id][points]=parameter

```
//Assume Assessment contains the id and the parameter
@PUT("url")
Call putElements(@Query(???) Assessment... assessmentIds);
```

Example Output:
https://baseurl.com/url?assessment[id1][points]=3&assessment[id2][points]=5

Is there a clean way to accomplish this in RetroFit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for `@QueryMap`

You will use it like this:

```
// sender
Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.add("assessmentid1points", "3");
parameters.add("assessmentid2points", "5");
parameters.add("key3", "value3");

yourObject.putElements(parameters);

// receiver interface
@PUT("url")
Call putElements(@QueryMap Map<String,String> parameters);
```

I've written a few tutorials on Retrofit 1 and 2, in case you want to check them out, [here](http://toomanytutorials.blogspot.com/p/homepage.html)